# Adding user list in the StreamingClient in Tweepy

Tags: real-time, tweepy, twitterapi-python, sttwitterapi, twitter-api-v2

I am writing the code for listening to the real-time Tweets from a specific list of users (more than 500 users). I read the Tweepy library documentation, and I could not find how to add the user list. Following is my code:

```
    import tweepy
brearer_token = "XXXXXXX-XXXXX"
class tweetListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        print(raw_data)

stream = tweetListener(bearer_token=bearer_token)
user_list = ['user_id1', 'user_id2']
stream.filter(user_fields = user_list)
```

Going through the documentation, I came across that in the `filter()` there is a parameter name `user_fields`. However, this encountered 400 errors.

Answer (score 0):

The [`user_fields`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/expansions_and_fields.html#user-fields-parameter) parameter of [`StreamingClient.filter`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient.filter) is used to specify the fields you want for User objects.

Instead, you need to add rules with [`StreamingClient.add_rules`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient.add_rules).

For more information, you can refer to [the guide to using `StreamingClient` in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/streaming.html#using-streamingclient) and [the Twitter API guide on building rules for filtered stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule).